# How to compare data from two tables using comparison operators stored in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to build a script to compare data from two different tables, using comparison operators stored in database.

I achieved to solve by two ways:

1. using dynamic SQL
2. using case statements

but I would like to solve using something that not includes dynamic SQL or case statements.

This is my base data table:

```
    create table #BaseData
    (
        ID int identity (1,1),
        numR int,
        ALertCode varchar (10),
        numOp     int,
        BaseOrder int,
        Criteri varchar (50),
        Operator varchar (5),
        BaseValue int
    )

    insert into #BaseData (numR, AlertCode, numOp, BaseOrder, Criteri, Operator, BaseValue)
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) numR,    ALertCode, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ALertCode order by AlertCode )numOp,
    DatosBase.BaseOrder, Criteri,           Operator, DatosBase.ComparisonValue BaseValue 
    from 
    (             select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 1  BaseOrder, 'ES_CV_Basal                 'Criteri,   '='     Operator,    1     ComparisonValue
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 2  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_Basal           '        ,  '='             ,    19 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 3  BaseOrder, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 4  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 5  BaseOrder, 'ES_CV_Basal_01              '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 6  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 7  BaseOrder, 'DiasCVPrevia_02             '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 8  BaseOrder, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all                                                                                    
                  select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 1  BaseOrder, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  '='             ,   1        
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 2  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '>'             ,   1000    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 3  BaseOrder, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 4  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 5  BaseOrder, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 6  BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 7  BaseOrder, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 8  BaseOrder, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL 
        union all                                                                                    
                  select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 1     BaseOrder, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 2     BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '>='            ,   1000        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 3     BaseOrder, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 4     BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  '='             ,   19      
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 5     BaseOrder, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 6     BaseOrder, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 7     BaseOrder, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 8     BaseOrder, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL                                                                                                         
    )BaseData
    order by ALertCode, BaseOrder
```

and this is my comparison data table:

```
    create table #ComparisonData 
    (
      ID int identity (1,1),
      ComparisonOrder int, 
      EvaluationCriteri varchar(50),
      ComparisonValue decimal (10,6)
    )

    insert into #ComparisonData  (ComparisonOrder, EvaluationCriteri, ComparisonValue)
    select ComparisonOrder, EvaluationCriteri, ComparisonValue
    from        
    (             select 1  ComparisonOrder,    'ES_CV_Basal'   EvaluationCriteri, 2        ComparisonValue
        union all select 2       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   EvaluationCriteri, 1001     ComparisonValue
        union all select 3       ,  'TDias'             EvaluationCriteri, 169      ComparisonValue
        union all select 4       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   EvaluationCriteri, 19       ComparisonValue
        union all select 5       ,  'TDias'             EvaluationCriteri, 169      ComparisonValue
        union all select 6       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   EvaluationCriteri, 387      ComparisonValue
        union all select 7       ,  'TDias'             EvaluationCriteri, 265      ComparisonValue
        union all select 8       ,  'Dif_CVe_CVp'       EvaluationCriteri, -0.33    ComparisonValue
    )ComparisonData
```

and this is my table to compare data:

```
    create table #AlertDetected 
    (
        ID int identity (1,1),
        numR int, 
        AlertCode   varchar (10), 
        numOp       int, 
        BaseOrder   int, 
        Criteri varchar(50), 
        Operator    varchar(5), 
        BaseValue   int,
        ComparisonOrder     int,
        EvaluationCriteri varchar (50),
        ComparisonValue decimal(10,6)
    )


    insert into #AlertDetected (numR, AlertCode, numOp, BaseOrder, Criteri, Operator, BaseValue, ComparisonOrder,   EvaluationCriteri, ComparisonValue)
    select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) numR, ALertCode, 
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ALertCode order by AlertCode )numOp,
                                                                            BaseOrder, Criteri, Operator, BaseValue, dc.ComparisonOrder,EvaluationCriteri, ComparisonValue
    from #BaseData db
    left join #ComparisonData  dc
    on db.BaseOrder = dc.ComparisonOrder
    where db.BaseValue is not null
```

This is my dynamic SQL solution:

```
    select  'select max(AlertResult)AlertResult  from ( ' + stuff(( select 'union all' + Operacion
    from 
    (   select   stuff(( select  +  concat (   ' ' , Operacion)
        from
        (   
            select numR, AlertCode,   BaseOrder,   concat (iif (numOp = 1 , '  select iif(  ', '  and  ' ),  ComparisonValue  ,  Operator , ' ', BaseValue)Operacion
            from 
            ( select numR, AlertCode,   BaseOrder, numOp , BaseValue ,  Operator ,  case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ComparisonValue ) else  cast ( ComparisonValue as float ) end ComparisonValue -- 
              from #AlertDetected 
            )t  
        )x
        where x.AlertCode =  isc.AlertCode FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  + '  ,  '+''''+AlertCode+''''+ ', '+ ''''+'0'+ '''' + ' )   AlertResult   '   as Operacion
        from #AlertDetected  isc group by AlertCode      
    )X
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 9, '')  + ' ) Datos'as CamposInforme
```

And this is my case statments solution:

```
select  iif (sum(Result)  = row_count , AlertCode, ' ')AlertDetected
from
( select  numR, AlertCode, numOp, BaseOrder, Criteri, ComparisonValue, Operator, BaseValue,                         
                    case    when Operator ='=' then iif (ComparisonValue = BaseValue, 1,0) 
                            when Operator ='<' then iif (ComparisonValue < BaseValue, 1,0) 
                            when Operator ='>' then iif (ComparisonValue > BaseValue, 1,0) 
                            when Operator ='>=' then iif (ComparisonValue >= BaseValue, 1,0) 
                            when Operator ='<=' then iif (ComparisonValue <= BaseValue, 1,0)  end Result , row_count
    from 
    (   select  numR, a.AlertCode, Criteri,  BaseOrder, numOp , BaseValue ,  Operator ,  
                case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ComparisonValue ) else  cast ( ComparisonValue as float ) end ComparisonValue , c.row_count 
        from #AlertDetected  a
        inner join 
    (       select AlertCode, COUNT(*) AS row_count
            FROM dbo.#AlertDetected 
            group by  AlertCode
        )c on a.AlertCode = c.AlertCode
    )d  
)d  group by AlertCode, row_count
```

I need to compare the data between the ComparisonValue and BaseValue columns based on the comparison operators, and I must obtain the alert code that complies with exactly each one of the comparisons between ComparisonValue and BaseValue.

There will be some way to achieve it without using dynamic SQL or case statement ?

Comment: What's wrong with either of them? Too verbose, error prone, other? What are you looking for? I would personally go for `CASE` clauses since they are pure SQL.

Comment: Can you show us how you solved this with dynamic SQL and case statements?  That would help us understand what you are trying to achieve.  But also - what is wrong with Case statements?

Comment: If the tables have the same schema, you can use the EXCEPT operator

Comment: But I need to compare the data between the ComparisonValue and BaseValue columns based on the comparison operators, and I must obtain the alert code that complies with exactly each one of the comparisons between ComparisonValue and BaseValue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Saw where you need a Hammer.
SQL is designed to very effectively persist data. It is not designed for this.
You should learn C# or Java. This could be done very easily in a proper language.

However, if you must use SQL then you should create a proc for each comparison. The procs should take an input of the two values you are comparing. That way, all the logic for doing that one comparison is contained in its own little capsule.

Call the proc you want dynamically by selecting the proc Name you will place in the table with the comparison operators.

If you want to do ">" , then the "GreaterThan" proc will get called as you pass in values to compare.

If you want to make this more efficient, create table types for kinds of things you will compare and then pass in a whole list of items at a time.

Comment: You're right, initially I tried to solve it with LINQ in C #. But ... I did not build the data model, I just have to make some reports, so early on i realize that it would be very complicated. My showed data, is depurated data, through many searches in SQL. I only asked about my final problem ...  then, there are many factors why I chose SQL to solve it, distributed data, complex searches to retrieve dates and others. 
So if you can help me, about how to make my script more efficient using table types
I will be gratefully.